# How to get <img> src value from xml file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, node.js, rss

I am trying to create a simple rss feed website.
I can get a few of rss feeds by just doing this:

```
let article = {
              'title': item.title,
              'image': item.image.url,
              'link': item.link,
              'description': item.description,
           }
```

Title and link work for most of rss feeds, but image and description do not.
Since a lot of rss fees has image as html inside of description like this:

```
{ title: 'The Rio Olympics Are Where TV Finally Sees the Future',
description: '<div class="rss_thumbnail"><img src="http://www.wired.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/GettyImages-587338962-660x435.jpg" alt="The Rio Olympics Are Where TV Finally Sees the Future" /></div>Time was, watching the Olympics just meant turning on your TV. That\'s changed—and there\'s no going back. The post <a href="http://www.wired.com/2016/08/rio-olympics-tv-finally-sees-future/">The Rio Olympics Are Where TV Finally Sees the Future</a> appeared first on <a href="http://www.wired.com">WIRED</a>.',...
```

How can I get image's url from it?

EDIT:

```
http.get("http://www.wired.com/feed/"...

  .on('readable', function()  {
        let stream = this;
        let item;
        while( item = stream.read()){
           let article = {
              'title': item.title,
              'image': item.image.url,
              'link': item.link,
              'description': item.description,
           }
           news.push(article);
        }
  })
```

this is some of my codes, and basically I am trying to get image url from Wired rss.
If I user 'image': item.image.url, it does not work. So what should I change it to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use xml2js for converting xml to json

```
var parseString = require('xml2js').parseString;

var xml = '<img title=\'A San Bernardino County Fire Department firefighter watches a helitanker make a water drop on a wildfire, seen from Cajon Boulevard in Devore, Calif., Thursday, Aug. 18, 2016. (David Pardo/The Daily Press via AP)\' height=\'259\' alt=\'APTOPIX California Wildfires\' width=\'460\' src=\'http://i.cbc.ca/1.3730399.1471835992!/cpImage/httpImage/image.jpg_gen/derivatives/16x9_460/aptopix-california-wildfires.jpg\' />';

parseString(xml, function (err, result) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 4));
    console.log(result["img"]["$"]["src"]);
});
```

Comment: I tried your answer, but it didn't work. I edited and added some of my codes.

Comment: @Dan I am sorry that the code failed for you.... where did the code fail.... it was supposed to fetch the 'url' from a string... also could you tell what changes you made in it....

Answer (score 0):

Use regex of string:

```
var res = description.match(/src=.*\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)/gi);
```

[Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/wx38rz5L/2265/)

Comment: I tried your answer, but it didn't work. I edited and added some of my codes.

Answer (score 0):

One idea would be to use regular expressions. For ex:

```
var re = /(src=)(\\'htt.*\\')/g
var img_string = "your image tag string"
var match = re.exec(img_string)
var result = match[1]
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use DOMDocument parser to get Image source.

```
$html = "<img title=\'A San Bernardino County Fire Department firefighter watches a helitanker make a water drop on a wildfire, seen from Cajon Boulevard in Devore, Calif., Thursday, Aug. 18, 2016. (David Pardo/The Daily Press via AP)\' height=\'259\' alt=\'APTOPIX California Wildfires\' width=\'460\' src=\'http://i.cbc.ca/1.3730399.1471835992!/cpImage/httpImage/image.jpg_gen/derivatives/16x9_460/aptopix-california-wildfires.jpg\' />";

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$src = $xpath->evaluate("string(//img/@src)"); # "/images/image.jpg"
```

Comment: Where did OP say he wanted PHP?